# How do I limit the file size so my program creates a new file after it becomes too large? and edit the name of the newly created file?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

As I run my code it builds the text file which quickly exceeds a size where I can effectively use it.

How would I set a size limit to the text size so that it creates a new text file with a title +1 of the previous file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void Crack(string password, vector<char> Chars)
{

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("pass.txt");


    myfile<<"PASSWORDs TO CRACK: 0 to "<<password<<endl;
    int n = Chars.size();
    int i = 0;
    while(true)
        {
            i++;
            int N = 1;
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)N*=n;
            for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
                {
                    int K = 1;
                    string crack = "";
                    for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
                        {
                            crack += Chars[j/K%n];
                            K *= n;
                        }
                    myfile<< crack<<" "<<endl;
                    if(password.compare(crack) == 0){
                    myfile<<"Cracked password: "<<crack<<endl;
                    return;
                    myfile.close();
                    }
                }
        }
}
int main()
{
    vector<char> Chars;
    for(char c = '0';c<='z';c++){
    if(islower(c) || isdigit(c))Chars.push_back(c);
    }
    Crack("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", Chars);
}
```

Comment: This is not a script, and C++ is a programming language, not a scripting language.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on language. Do you have any input on the actual question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ostream::tellp` to give you the current file size. If it exceeds the limit, close the stream and create a new file.

What do you mean by "title+1"? Do you mean the file name or do you want to print a header in each file?

Comment: When I said title+1 I was referring to the name of the text document. For example, the first file will be pass.txt followed by pass1.txt ...  etc. Also, I was hoping for an automated approach since I this is a brute force approach to cracking a hash.